autoreload python without master in uwsgi + flask
I have a Flask server, and for several reasons I need to set master = false in my uwsgi configuration. But due to this, I'm not able to auto reload on file changes anymore.
This is my uwsgi ini
[uwsgi]
master = false
enable-threads = true
wsgi-file = /opt/merlin/main.py
callable = app
protocol = http
http-socket = localhost:5000
daemonize = /var/log/merlin/merlin-app.log
env = FLASK_ENV=development
py-autoreload = 1

The reason that I need to use master = false is that I'm importing pandas and google.cloud.bigquery, and this causes the errors:
uWSGI listen queue of socket "localhost:5000" (fd: 3) full !!! (2871782829/10922)

Not exactly sure about the issue. Exploring more I found that it's related to PIL probably that causes it to not run with master = true.
So, is there any way to run python auto reload in uwsgi with master = false?

You should always run with master = true unless you really know what you're doing. The listen queue warning is likely not related to importing pandas/bigquery/PIL at all.

@AKX when i only comment out the pandas/bq/PIL imports without any other changes, the warning goes and the reload works fine with master = true

Well, is it possible that the imports take enough time that the listen queue ends up filling with requests that are not yet ready to be served?

@AKX there are zero requests coming to the server. the warnings just starts showing up when i start the server.

That could be an uwsgi bug too – the queue and max_queue values (2871782829/10922) seem to be pretty bogus. For the heck of it, try adding a regular uwsgi socket (socket = /tmp/whatever.sock) to see if that helps?

@AKX Tried it. No luck. Thanks for the help though. I'll go through the issues if there's anything that's similar to my problem.

One more thing: Try http = localhost:5000 instead of protocol = http and http-socket = localhost:5000?

@AKX the server didn't go up this time. (have also set master = true and socket = /tmp/whatever.sock). nothing in logs after:
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 96)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 230, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 232)

Are you sure it didn't? You're using daemonize, so logs would go there...

@AKX You're right, the server was up. With this, I don't get the socket full messages anymore, and the autoreload functionality worked too!! It's just super slow to restart and I see this in the logs  worker 1 (pid: 298) is taking too much time to die...NO MERCY . No idea whats wrong here, something seems to be blocking the process from dying. Anyway, if you drop an answer, I can accept it. I have no idea why that worked though. Thanks.

To sum up the discussion in the comments:

Use master = true whenever you can. You'll need it for many of uWSGI's nicer features.
Using http = localhost:5000 has uWSGI spin up a separate http-parsing/routing process; http-socket = ... does a different (worse) thing and protocol = http just sets the default protocol to be http, which you don't want. This is discussed here and here.
Preferably don't use daemonize =  at all; use your system's process manager (e.g. systemd) to manage uWSGI and where it logs to.

